# Cannot read property "down" of undefined

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdxHS.png)I am trying to test a button in a component.

..........
`like so`
.........

```
   import React, { Children } from "react";
   import Enzyme, { shallow, mount, render } from "enzyme";
   import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
   import axios from "axios.js";
   import data from "./mockData";
   import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
   import SegmentationLanding from "./SegmentationLanding";
   import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

   Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

   jest.mock("axios.js");
   const flushPromises = () => {
      return new Promise((resolve) => setImmediate(resolve));
    };

 describe(`The segmentation lists`, () => {
   let wrapper;
   beforeEach(() => {
      wrapper = shallow(<SegmentationLanding />);
   });
  test("the total number of records", async () => {
         await flushPromises();
       const w1 = mount(
      <BrowserRouter>
       <SegmentationLanding />
       </BrowserRouter>
     );
    const btn = getByTestId("jest-tester");
    expect(btn).toBeDisabled();
```

});
});

When i try to test, i get the error cannot read "down" property of undefined. Can anyone please suggest where i went wrong? I just wrote a simple test to test the button is disabled or not.

Comment: Can you share the exact error? where is it coming from?

Comment: The mount method is giving the error. It is not able to mount the component and find method gives the undefined error.

Comment: I have added the screenshot at the link in the start.. You can check the error. Can you help me with this error as i am having a lot of problems related to this.

Comment: I have added the screenshot at the link in the start.. You can check the error. Can you help me with this error as i am having a lot of problems related to this. I am using react 16.8 and enzyme 16 and 17 (both i have installed and using one) though they might not be compatible with each other. [link @wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17 ]

Comment: I don't see any use of the `mount` function.

Comment: Its there in the screen shot ...